# How to split a dataframe into dataframes with same column values?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe, apache-spark-sql

Using Scala, how can I split dataFrame into multiple dataFrame (be it array or collection) with same column value. 
For example I want to split the following DataFrame:

```
ID  Rate    State
1   24  AL
2   35  MN
3   46  FL
4   34  AL
5   78  MN
6   99  FL
```

to:

data set 1

```
ID  Rate    State
1   24  AL  
4   34  AL
```

data set 2

```
ID  Rate    State
2   35  MN
5   78  MN
```

data set 3

```
ID  Rate    State
3   46  FL
6   99  FL
```

Comment: Why do you need to split the dataframe in multiple dataframes?. As probably you know you can filter and transform your dataFrame To:
[(AL,Seq(24 AL, 4 34 AL)), (MN, Seq(35 MN, 5 78 MN)), (FL, Seq(46 FL 6 99 FL))] Using groupBy.

Comment: groupBy gives GroupDate type, how can I convert that to Array?

Comment: can you explain what are you trying to do with that array?

Comment: Use filter  no need every time new data frame

Answer (score 23):

You can collect unique state values and simply map over resulting array:

```
val states = df.select("State").distinct.collect.flatMap(_.toSeq)
val byStateArray = states.map(state => df.where($"State" <=> state))
```

or to map:

```
val byStateMap = states
    .map(state => (state -> df.where($"State" <=> state)))
    .toMap
```

The same thing in Python:

```py
from itertools import chain
from pyspark.sql.functions import col

states = chain(*df.select("state").distinct().collect())

# PySpark 2.3 and later
# In 2.2 and before col("state") == state) 
# should give the same outcome, ignoring NULLs 
# if NULLs are important 
# (lit(state).isNull() & col("state").isNull()) | (col("state") == state)
df_by_state = {state: 
  df.where(col("state").eqNullSafe(state)) for state in states}
```

The obvious problem here is that it requires a full data scan for each level, so it is an expensive operation. If you're looking for a way to just split the output see also [How do I split an RDD into two or more RDDs?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32970709/1560062)

In particular you can write `Dataset` partitioned by the column of interest:

```
val path: String = ???
df.write.partitionBy("State").parquet(path)
```

and read back if needed:

```
// Depend on partition prunning
for { state <- states } yield spark.read.parquet(path).where($"State" === state)

// or explicitly read the partition
for { state <- states } yield spark.read.parquet(s"$path/State=$state")
```

Depending on the size of the data, number of levels of the splitting, storag and persistence level of the input it might faster or slower than multiple filters.

Comment: Maybe Kind of late question. But when I try the python Code in Spark 2.2.0 I always get a "Column is not callable" error. I tried several approaches but still I get the same error. Any Workarounds for this?

Comment: you need to import `col` with `from pyspark.sql.functions import col `

Answer (score 2):

It is very simple (if the spark version is 2) if you make the dataframe as a temporary table.

```
df1.createOrReplaceTempView("df1")
```

And now you can do the queries,

```
var df2 = spark.sql("select * from df1 where state = 'FL'")
var df3 = spark.sql("select * from df1 where state = 'MN'")
var df4 = spark.sql("select * from df1 where state = 'AL'")
```

Now you got the df2, df3, df4. If you want to have them as list, you can use,

```
df2.collect()
df3.collect()
```

or even map/filter function. Please refer https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-programming-guide.html#datasets-and-dataframes

Ash

Comment: is there a possibility to loop SQL queries in spark? Collecting all distinct values before and then replacing the "where state = 'FL'" with "where state = 'i'" or something like this?

Comment: It will be overhead but still you can handle it using Spark Dataframes and SCALA coding

Comment: I used the same to split a DF into 5 sub-DF for doing left joins, the resultant DF is a view and not an independent DF on its own, its messing with left joins, can I split into independent DF ??

Answer (score 0):

you can use ..

```
var stateDF = df.select("state").distinct()  // to get states in a df
val states = stateDF.rdd.map(x=>x(0)).collect.toList //to get states in a list

for (i <- states)  //loop to get each state
{
    var finalDF = sqlContext.sql("select * from table1 where state = '" + state
    +"' ")
}
```