# Spark: Row filter based on Column value

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe

I have millions of rows as dataframe like this:

```
val df = Seq(("id1", "ACTIVE"), ("id1", "INACTIVE"), ("id1", "INACTIVE"), ("id2", "ACTIVE"), ("id3", "INACTIVE"), ("id3", "INACTIVE")).toDF("id", "status")

scala> df.show(false)
+---+--------+
|id |status  |
+---+--------+
|id1|ACTIVE  |
|id1|INACTIVE|
|id1|INACTIVE|
|id2|ACTIVE  |
|id3|INACTIVE|
|id3|INACTIVE|
+---+--------+
```

Now I want to divide this data into three separate dataFrame like this:

1. Only ACTIVE ids (like id2), say activeDF
2. Only INACTIVE ids (like id3), say inactiveDF
3. Having both ACTIVE and INACTIVE as status, say bothDF

How can I calculate *activeDF* and *inactiveDF*?

I know that *bothDF* can be calculated like

```
df.select("id").distinct.except(activeDF).except(inactiveDF)
```

, but this will involve shuffling (as 'distinct' operation required same). Is there any better way to calculate *bothDF*

Versions:

```
Spark : 2.2.1
Scala : 2.11
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just another way - groupBy, collect as set and then if the size of the set is 1, it is either active or inactive only, else both

```
scala> val df = Seq(("id1", "ACTIVE"), ("id1", "INACTIVE"), ("id1", "INACTIVE"), ("id2", "ACTIVE"), ("id3", "INACTIVE"), ("id3", "INACTIVE"), ("id4", "ACTIVE"), ("id5", "ACTIVE"), ("id6", "INACTIVE"), ("id7", "ACTIVE"), ("id7", "INACTIVE")).toDF("id", "status")
df: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [id: string, status: string]

scala> df.show(false)
+---+--------+
|id |status  |
+---+--------+
|id1|ACTIVE  |
|id1|INACTIVE|
|id1|INACTIVE|
|id2|ACTIVE  |
|id3|INACTIVE|
|id3|INACTIVE|
|id4|ACTIVE  |
|id5|ACTIVE  |
|id6|INACTIVE|
|id7|ACTIVE  |
|id7|INACTIVE|
+---+--------+


scala> val allstatusDF = df.groupBy("id").agg(collect_set("status") as "allstatus")
allstatusDF: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [id: string, allstatus: array<string>]

scala> allstatusDF.show(false)
+---+------------------+
|id |allstatus         |
+---+------------------+
|id7|[ACTIVE, INACTIVE]|
|id3|[INACTIVE]        |
|id5|[ACTIVE]          |
|id6|[INACTIVE]        |
|id1|[ACTIVE, INACTIVE]|
|id2|[ACTIVE]          |
|id4|[ACTIVE]          |
+---+------------------+


scala> allstatusDF.withColumn("status", when(size($"allstatus") === 1, $"allstatus".getItem(0)).otherwise("BOTH")).show(false)
+---+------------------+--------+
|id |allstatus         |status  |
+---+------------------+--------+
|id7|[ACTIVE, INACTIVE]|BOTH    |
|id3|[INACTIVE]        |INACTIVE|
|id5|[ACTIVE]          |ACTIVE  |
|id6|[INACTIVE]        |INACTIVE|
|id1|[ACTIVE, INACTIVE]|BOTH    |
|id2|[ACTIVE]          |ACTIVE  |
|id4|[ACTIVE]          |ACTIVE  |
+---+------------------+--------+
```

Comment: Thanks @Gadipally. Operation performed using one ShuffledRowRDD

Answer (score 2):

The most elegant solution is to pivot on `status`

```
val counts = df
  .groupBy("id")
  .pivot("status", Seq("ACTIVE", "INACTIVE"))
  .count
```

or equivalent direct `agg`

```
val counts = df
  .groupBy("id")
  .agg(
    count(when($"status" === "ACTIVE", true)) as "ACTIVE",
    count(when($"status" === "INACTIVE", true)) as "INACTIVE"
  )
```

followed by a simple `CASE ... WHEN`:

```
val result = counts.withColumn(
  "status",
  when($"ACTIVE" === 0, "INACTIVE")
    .when($"inactive" === 0, "ACTIVE")
    .otherwise("BOTH")
)

result.show
```

```
+---+------+--------+--------+                                                  
| id|ACTIVE|INACTIVE|  status|
+---+------+--------+--------+
|id3|     0|       2|INACTIVE|
|id1|     1|       2|    BOTH|
|id2|     1|       0|  ACTIVE|
+---+------+--------+--------+
```

Later you can separate the `result` with `filters` or dump to disk with source that supports `partitionBy` ([How to split a dataframe into dataframes with same column values?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31669308/10938362)).

Comment: Thanks, it worked but performance of code posted by Gadipally is better