# PySpark split DataFrame into multiple frames based on a column key and train an ML lib model on each

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I have a PySpark dataframe with a column "group". I also have feature columns and a label column. I want to split the dataframe for each group and then train a model and end up with a dictionary where the keys are the "group" names and the values are the trained models.

[This question essentially give an answer to this problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31669308/how-to-split-a-dataframe-into-dataframes-with-same-column-values). This method is inefficient.

> The obvious problem here is that it requires a full data scan for each level, so it is an expensive operation.

The answer is old and I am hoping there have been improvements in PySpark since then. For my use case I have 10k groups, with heavy skew in the data sizes. The largest group can have 1 Billion records and the smallest group can have 1 record.

Edit: As suggested here is a small reproducible example.

```
df = sc.createDataFrame(
    [
        ('A', 1, 0, True),
        ('A', 3, 0, False),
        ('B', 2, 2, True),
        ('B', 3, 3, True),
        ('B', 5, 2, False)
    ],
    ('group', 'feature_1', 'feature_2', 'label')
)
```

I can split the data as suggested in the above link:

```
from itertools import chain
from pyspark.sql.functions import col

groups = chain(*df.select("group").distinct().collect())
df_by_group = {group: 
  train_model(df.where(col("group").eqNullSafe(group))) for group in groups}
```

Where `train_model` is a function that takes a dataframe with columns=`[feature_1, feature_2, label]` and returns a trained model on that dataframe.

Comment: Please give us a small [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48427185/how-to-make-good-reproducible-apache-spark-examples).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I added an example, let me know if it is more clear now.

Comment: use `df.sampleBy('group', fractions={group:xx})` for each group in groups, calculating xx is trivial. http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.4.0/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.DataFrame.sampleBy

Comment: How does this help with applying the training function to each subgroup @jxc?

Comment: @Heraiwa, is your question to take a fraction of rows with a specific `group` value  (instead of all matched rows) from a large dataset?

Comment: No, my question is regarding applying a generalized function (like a UDAF but more general) to a DataFrame.

Comment: Maybe you should use a pandas udf function. First you do a repartition on the data, by the group you want. Later you define a udf function using a decorator. Later you apply this function for every partitioned data. You can find how to use UDF functions in Databricks webpage.