# How to iterate an array(string) for Null/Blank value check in Pyspark

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I am new to Pyspark. 
By using the below dataframe how can I divide it to two different dataframe based on the "_Value" field. If the _Value which is array(string) is having any null or blank elements in it, then it should go to one dataframe and the rest into another.

```
+----+-----+-----+-------------------------------+-------------+--------------+
|key |Size |Color|AdditionalAttributeMetric      |_Name        |_Value        |
+----+-----+-----+-------------------------------+-------------+--------------+
|123k|BLACK|black|[Size -> BLACK, Color -> black]|[Size, Color]|[BLACK, black]|
|123k|WHITE|null |[Size -> WHITE, Color ->]      |[Size, Color]|[WHITE,]      |
+----+-----+-----+-------------------------------+-------------+--------------+
```

Below is the complete code, but its throwing an error "Column is not iterable".

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
from pyspark.sql.functions import *
from pyspark.sql.types import *
from pyspark.sql.functions import lit, col, create_map
from itertools import chain

rdd = sc.parallelize([('123k', 'BLACK', 'black'),
                      ('123k', 'WHITE', None)
                          ])

schema = StructType([StructField('key', StringType(), True),
                     StructField('Size', StringType(), True),
                     StructField('Color', StringType(), True)])

df_struct = sqlContext.createDataFrame(rdd, schema)

df_struct_subattri = df_struct.select("Size", "Color")

AdditionalAttributeMetric = create_map(
            list(chain(*((lit(name), col(name)) for name in df_struct_subattri.columns)))).alias(
            "AdditionalAttributeMetric")

df_struct = df_struct.select("*", AdditionalAttributeMetric)

df_struct = df_struct.withColumn("_Name", map_keys(col("AdditionalAttributeMetric")))
df_struct = df_struct.withColumn("_Value", map_values(col("AdditionalAttributeMetric")))


df_struct1 = df_struct.select("*").where(array_contains (col("_Value"), '') | array_contains (col("_Value"), lit(None)))

df_struct1.show(truncate = False)
```

Any kind of help is appreciated.

Comment: Hello your question may be a duplicate of this one : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31669308/how-to-split-a-dataframe-into-dataframes-with-same-column-values

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sample data has 1 clean row, 1 row with `None`, 1 row with `''`.

```
from pyspark.sql import function as F
df_struct.show()

+----+--------------+
| key|        _value|
+----+--------------+
|123k|[BLACK, black]|
|123k|      [WHITE,]|
|124k|      [BLUE, ]|
+----+--------------+
```

**If you do not have spark2.4,** you can use `array_contains` to check for empty string. Doing this if any row has null in it, the output for array_contains will be `null`, or if it has empty string "" in it, output will be `true`. You can then `filter` on that new `boolean` column as shown below.

```
df.withColumn("boolean", F.array_contains("_value", ""))\
  .filter(~((F.col("boolean")==True) | (F.col("boolean").isNull()))).drop("boolean").show()

+----+--------------+
| key|        _value|
+----+--------------+
|123k|[BLACK, black]|
+----+--------------+
```

You can remove `~` to get all other rows with **Nones or empty strings**.

```
df.withColumn("boolean", F.array_contains("_value", ""))\
  .filter(((F.col("boolean")==True) | (F.col("boolean").isNull()))).drop("boolean").show()

+----+--------+
| key|  _value|
+----+--------+
|123k|[WHITE,]|
|124k|[BLUE, ]|
+----+--------+
```

**Spark2.4:**

You can use higher order function **array** `filter` to take out `None` or `''`, and then compare `size` in the **dataframe** `filter`.

```
df_struct.withColumn("_value2", F.expr("""filter(_value, x-> x is not null and x!='')"""))\
  .filter((F.size("_value2")==F.size("_value"))).drop("_value2").show()

+----+--------------+
| key|        _value|
+----+--------------+
|123k|[BLACK, black]|
+----+--------------+
```

To get the other rows, which have **Nones or '' or both**. You can put `~` in front of filter expression.

```
df_struct.withColumn("_value2", F.expr("""filter(_value, x-> x is not null and x!='')"""))\
  .filter(~(F.size("_value2")==F.size("_value"))).drop("_value2").show()

+----+--------+
| key|  _value|
+----+--------+
|123k|[WHITE,]|
|124k|[BLUE, ]|
+----+--------+
```

You can **also use** higher order function **`exists`**.

```
df.withColumn("boolean", F.expr("""exists(_value, x-> x is null or x=='')"""))\
  .filter(~(F.col("boolean")==True)).drop("boolean").show()

+----+--------------+
| key|        _value|
+----+--------------+
|123k|[BLACK, black]|
+----+--------------+
```

Remove `~` to get all rows with `Nones` or `""`:

```
df.withColumn("boolean", F.expr("""exists(_value, x-> x is null or x=='')"""))\
  .filter((F.col("boolean")==True)).drop("boolean").show()

+----+--------+
| key|  _value|
+----+--------+
|123k|[WHITE,]|
|124k|[BLUE, ]|
+----+--------+
```